# How to get rid of TS problem/error messages in the VS-Code editor?

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code

### The Issue at Hand:

While using VSCode I am being notified twice of problems that occur inside of my documents. I found that other people were have problems that sounded similar, but I couldn't find a Q&A with a solution that helped. The most obvious place to look is in the VSCode settings. I tried several different  settings that I read had help others in similar situations, but to no avail. Below is the list of settings I attempted to configure in hopes of finding a solution.

```
{
  "typescript.format.enable": false,
  "typescript.validate.enable": false,
  "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": false,
  "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.strictFunctionTypes": false,
  "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": false,
  "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.strictNullChecks": false,
}
```

---

#### More Detailed Explanation

Every forum/Q&A I visited, I never found someone who I felt was try to solve exactly the same issue that I am experiencing, I feel this is in part because it doesn't cause any hindrance, only annoyance. Some people probably rely on the problem notifications that I am trying to get rid of.
The issue due to the fact that I use ESLint, and Prettier. I equip ESLint with a plugin that gives the linter the ability to communicate with Prettier, which in turn, allows both Prettier and ESLint to communicate harmoniously to me through VSCode. ESLint & Prettier notify of every problem in my code I need to be aware of, therefore; I don't need to be notified by some other mechanism. The unwanted notifications come with a TS code every time they pop-up, because of this & the fact its VSCode, I am guessing it is a TypeScript/JavaScript formatter that comes with VSCode out-of-the-box, though I am pretty confident that, that is what it is, at this point I don't truly know. It is odd I don't see other people asking about *"unwanted TS codes in the VSCode editor".*

---

#### Demonstration of the Issue:

Below is a screenshot of my VSCode problems panel that demonstrates what is happening. In the screenshot I am intentionally causing an error by typing the Keyword function into the editor, followed by nothing else. You can see that ESLint is working as it should, it notifies me that there is a problem with entering the keyword function without any other code following. You'll notice **it says there are 2 problems**, though their is clearly only one, and that some mechanism other than my linter, and formatter is notifying me of the same problem. This annoys the hell-O out of me, because I can't trust the badges when they pop-up with a problem count, and I have to look through two sets of error codes to figure out why the editor is complaining.

[image: ProblemNotifyingUserTwice]

---

#### In Final: Making the Question Being Asked Concise:

- What I am asking, or what i would like to know, is this:

> "How can I turn off the problem notifications that display the TS codes as shown in the image above. How can I configure VSCode so that only the formatter &/or linter of my choice notifies me of problems, so that I am not being notified of a single problem multiple times, by multiple processes ???"

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `"typescript.validate.enable": false` for TS files and `"javascript.validate.enable": false` for JS files

This disables errors from the built-in JS/TS extension

Comment: Honored to have you answer this, your solution was exactly what I wanted. Thank you Matt!